# JsRender - dynamic array, helper function

Tags: arrays, json, jsrender

I have a website with JsRender and a JSON file.
My JSRender code:

```
{{for ~getModel(cards)}}
{{:id}}
{{/for}}
```

My JSON file:

```
{
    "alpha": {
        "cards": [{
            "id": "alpha-01"
        }, {
            "id": "alpha-02"
        }, {
            "id": "alpha-03"
        }]
    },
    "beta": {
        "cards": [{
            "id": "beta-01"
        }, {
            "id": "beta-02"
        }]
    }
}
```

In `{{for ~getModel(cards)}}` is `cards`, a suffix.
My JsRender helper concatenates a prefix and a suffix and the result is a string.
This string should be my array for the `for` loop. The suffix is a dynamic part, a parameter from the URL (`?model=alpha`)

The for loop should run through the array `alpha.cards` -> `{{for ~getModel(alpha.cards)}}`

But when I concate the dynamic part and the suffix, the return value is a string, and the `for` loop doesn't work. It seems the value (return) for the helper must be an array.

Is that right or is there a another solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you need to return an array. JsRender renders against javascript objects and arrays (typically a hierarchy of objects and arrays). If your string is a JSON string you need to convert/eval first to produce the corresponding object or array...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My solution was: `$.views.helpers({ getModel: function() { return this.data[byModel]; } });` and it works! `byModel` contains `alpha` as string.